# How to prevent Array from crashing while simultaneously adding and deleting rows?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this `circles` array that results in Circles being created at random positions, and then fading out. Upon a circle faded out I need to completely delete it, which is achieved by removing the corresponding row in the array after a delay equal to the end of the fade-out animation.

It works fine as long as I click the "add circle" button less frequently than the deletion speed. However, when I keep pressing it fast, the view crashes with an `index out of range`. This appears to be the result of the algorithm getting confused: it identifies the row to be deleted by its index, but in the meantime other rows could have been deleted/added, which means indexes are already different.

Please see:

```
import SwiftUI

let screenW = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
let screenH = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

struct PlayGround: View {
    
    struct BlackCircle {
        var id = UUID()
        var position: CGPoint
        var opacity: Double = 1
    }
    
    @State var circles: [BlackCircle] = []
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            

            ForEach(Array(circles.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) {
                index, item in
                Circle()
                    .frame(width:30, height:30)
                    .position(item.position)
                    .opacity(item.opacity)
                    .onAppear {
                        
                        let animation = Animation.linear(duration: 1)
                        
                        withAnimation(animation) {
                            circles[index].opacity = 0
                        }
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                            circles.remove(at: index)
                        }
                            
                        
                    }
                
                
            }.frame(width: screenW, height:screenH)
            
            
            Button(action: {
                
                let randx = CGFloat.random(in: 30...screenW-30)
                let randy = CGFloat.random(in: 30...screenH-30)
                let randpos = CGPoint(x: randx, y: randy)
                
                circles.append(BlackCircle(position: randpos))
                

            }, label: {
                Text("Add a Circle")
            })
            
        }
    }
}
```

The easiest and no-effort way to solve this is to just **not** remove the row when the circle has faded out. This is surely both inelegant and inefficient though (would possibly end up with thousands of useless rows in the array). So how would I go about preventing the array from crashing when new elements are being added and delay-deleted all the time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is due to the index being out of range, try removing the circles based on id instead of index:

```
circles.removeAll { (existingCircle) -> Bool in
     return existingCircle.id == item.id
}
```

Comment: You were faster) Take this answer

Comment: Ok, thank you both for the perfect solution!

Answer (score 2):

Just use following delete method without using indexes

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    circles.removeAll { (circle) -> Bool in
        circle.id == item.id
    }
}
```